# How to get used data log android

Tags: android

Is there a way how to get data log like you can get sms or call log?

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();

Cursor c = contentResolver.query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,
    null, null, CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC");

int number = c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
int type = c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
int date = c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
int duration = c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
```

I need to know how many data I used by mobile connection (no wifi) last month to count with that in future.